# Servlet send arraylist to JSP as request attribute

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am attempting to send an ArrayList from a servlet to a JSP page.  In the Servlet:

```
List<ItemObj> myList = new ArrayList<ItemObj>();   
req.setAttribute("list", myList);
req.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(req,resp);
```

In the JSP:

```
<% List<ItemObj> myList = (ArrayList<ItemObj>) request.getParameter("list"); %>
```

However, I keep getting an error: Cannot cast from String to List.  I have found sources that indicate that I can cast as such:

[how to send ArrayList from jsp to servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988612/how-to-send-arraylist-from-jsp-to-servlet)

[Send array of objects from servlet to JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360223/send-array-of-objects-from-servlet-to-jsp)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `setAttribute` and `getParameter`. See anything wrong?

Comment: Also, **never** use scriptlets.

Comment: great catch, apologies.  I am new to JSP and still trying to get a good understanding of the difference between the two.  Thank you!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, why should I not use scriptlets?

Comment: It is highly discouraged, for reasons explained [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html).

Comment: @thepristinedesign plz close the question if u got ur answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `list` as request attribute and getting it back as request parameter

Use `<% List<ItemObj> myList = (ArrayList<ItemObj>) request.getAttribute("list"); %>`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `request.getParameter` use

`<% List<ItemObj> myList = (ArrayList<ItemObj>) request.getAttribute("list"); %>`

`request.getParameter`     is used to retrieve form parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Sotirious is spot-on. You need to call getAttribute.

But beyond that, you should be privy to the scope of your attribute:
is it scoped to (i) page, (ii) request, (iii) session, or (iv) application?

I don't know the default scope off-hand, but you might want to look into that.

Comment: I am intending here for page scope.  I'm guessing that attribute is a poor choice then?

Comment: I think setAttribute is the right call. Just make sure your scope is right.

Answer (score 0):

You need `request.getAttribute()` instead of `request.getParameter()`